# how to make multi url in a line of '- url:' ,on google-app-engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url

like this:

```
handlers:
- url: /media
  static_dir: media

- url: /form;/items.html
  script: validate.py
```

**/form;/items.html**

i want /form and /item.html  use validate.py

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL patterns are regular expressions, so you can simply provide a regular expression that matches both:

```
- url: /(form|items\.html)
  script: validate.py
```

Alternately, you can use multiple handlers, as Adam suggests, or just make validate.html your catchall (with an expression of '.*').

Answer (score 1):

List the handler twice in your app.yaml, e.g.:

```
handlers:
- url: /media
  static_dir: media

- url: /form\.html
  script: validate.py

- url: /items\.html
  script: validate.py
```

[Link to documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Script_Handlers).

Also note that you need to escape a full-stop (`.`) with a backslash (`\`), since "[URL and file path patterns use POSIX extended regular expression syntax...](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#About_app_yaml)".